# VSCode: how to configure task

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to configure the task runner as the following:

my goal is to execute the following command:
**`MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000" mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:run -Pxconfig-java`**

So the structure is **`MAVEN_OPTS {mavenOpts} mvn {taskName} {args}`**

My problem there are the `MAVEN_OPTS` declaration (anything before the command)

---

This what I got so far

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "showOutput": "always",
  "args": [
    "MAVEN_OPTS",
    "-Xdebug",
    "-Xnoagent",
    "-Djava.compiler=NONE",
    "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "command": "mvn",
      "taskName": "org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:run",
      "args": [
        "org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:run",
        "-P",
        "xconfig-java"
      ],
      "suppressTaskName": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Note I've tried the `supressTaskName` option that is supposed to do the trick: [DOCU](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_command-and-tasks)